# PowerShell: Get-ChildItem FullName Output to Get-FileHash Path

Tags: windows, powershell, command

New to PowerShell, I'm trying to create a command that does the following:

- Searches an entire directory for a specific file
- Uses the file path from Get-ChildItem as a variable for Get-FileHash "-Path"
- Lists the file's FullName, Attributes, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, $Hash ($Hash = output of Get-FileHash)

**What I've created so far (that doesn't work):**

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"; $Path = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\ -Force -Filter screenshot_37.png | Select-Object FullName; Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\ -Force -Filter screenshot_37.png |Select-Object FullName, Attributes, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, @{Name='Hash';Expression = { $_ |Get-FileHash $Path -Alogorithm MD5 |ForEach-Object Hash }}
```

Works As Is:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"; Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\ -Force -Filter screenshot_37.png |Select-Object FullName, Attributes, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, @{Name='Hash';Expression = { $_ |Get-FileHash -Alogorithm MD5 |ForEach-Object Hash }}
```

*Returns:*

FullName       : C:\Users\ME\Downloads\Screenshot_37.png

Attributes     : Hidden, Archive

LastWriteTime  : 10/24/2023 9:32:34 AM

CreationTime   : 10/24/2023 9:32:34 AM

LastAccessTime : 10/26/2023 10:37:31 AM

Hash           :

**Can someone help me in understanding and creating a working command for what's desired?**

($ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue" is present b/c User does not have Admin permissions, therefor searching the C:\ drive produces a lot of errors of access denied)

Comment: So what is the question ? Whats missing ?

Comment: The command fails to return any values. I'm looking for assistance (:

Comment: Just as an aside ...  to put your code in a single long line makes it unnecessarily hard to read. Please use line breaks. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\ -Force -Filter screenshot_37.png |
Select-Object FullName, Attributes, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, 
@{
    Name       = 'Hash';
    Expression = { Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5 | ForEach-Object Hash }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to call `Get-ChildItem` twice - instead, attach the output from `Get-FileHash` to the original file item:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\ -Force -Filter screenshot_37.png |Select-Object FullName, Attributes, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, @{Name='Hash';Expression = { $_ |Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 |ForEach-Object Hash }}
```

The last argument passed to `Select-Object` (`@{Name='Hash';Expression = { $_ |Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 |ForEach-Object Hash }}`) is a *calculated property table*, which allows you to synthesize new properties based on the existing input object.

You can read more about calculated properties in [the `about_Calculated_Properties` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information! That's amazing to know (:

Comment: I now need to figure out how to have Get-FileHash to pull from the FullName

Comment: @trblshootr I'm not sure I understand, can you clarify what you mean? If you want to pass the file path explicitly to `Get-FileHash` as an argument, simply change `{ $_ |Get-FileHash ... }` to `{ Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $_.FullName ... }`, but you really don't need to - PowerShell will automatically figure out that what you mean when you pipe a file object to `Get-FileHash`

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I've tried to run `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"; Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\ -Force -Filter screenshot_37.png |Select-Object FullName, Attributes, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, @{Name='Hash';Expression = { $_ |Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Alogorithm MD5 |ForEach-Object Hash }}` and it returns with an empty Hash

Comment: @trblshootr You can chose to either pipe the file object (`{ $_ |Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 ...}`), _or_ pass the path explicitly (`{ Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5 ...}`) - but not _both_ at once :)

Comment: I just realized there was a typo in the original answer (`-Alogorithm` instead of `-Algorithm`), try again

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen OH SNAPPPP! YOU'RE A WIZARD